# jQuery fadeOut callback error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firebug indicates I have a `TypeError: a.ownerDocument is undefined` with this code:

```
$(this).text('Updated!').fadeOut('900',  function() { 
  $(this).text('Update').attr('disabled', 'disabled').show()
});
```

A more complete snippet follows:

```
$(".update-role").click(function() {
  var newRole = $(this).prev().val();
  var userId  = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');  // e.g. 'user-role-18'
  userId = userId.split('-');
  userId = userId[2]; // so we get '18'
  $.getJSON('services/update_staff_role.php', {r: newRole, id: userId}, function(j) {
    if(j.result == 'success') {
    $(this).text('Updated!').fadeOut('900',  function() { 
          $(this).text('Update').attr('disabled', 'disabled').show()
        });
    } else {
      alert(j.reason);
    }
  });
  console.info(userId, newRole);
});
```

Could it be because I'm using `this`, because I'm using a `callback` inside another `callback`?

Comment: `this` is a button. I'm using jquery v1.7.2

Comment: no, this is not button in ajax call back :) log it to console and you'll see. Instead, save it reference before ajax `var self=this;` and then in ajax call back use `self` instead of `this`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `var _this = $(this);` then instead of `$(this).text..` use `_this.text...`, because `$(this)` refer to `$.getJSON`:

```
$(".update-role").click(function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var newRole = $(this).prev().val();
  var userId  = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
  userId = userId.split('-');
  userId = userId[2];
  $.getJSON('services/update_staff_role.php', {r: newRole, id: userId}, function(j) {
    if(j.result == 'success') {
    _this.text('Updated!').fadeOut('900',  function() { 
          $(this).text('Update').attr('disabled', 'disabled').show()
        });
    } else {
      alert(j.reason);
    }
  });
  console.info(userId, newRole);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Would `_this` also work inside the `fadeOut` callback?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour yes it will work, but you can keep `$(this)` it refer to `_this`

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `this`, when inside the callback, is not referring to the button that was clicked.  Before your call to $.getJSON, you could store the button reference in a variable, then access that variable in your callback.